# Regex for ISO8601 temporal duration but only with minutes and seconds

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to write Regex to match the ISO8601 standard for temporal durations, but only where `PT` and `M` or `S` are valid.

So far I have found a full example of ISO8601 regex but it is more complex than I need. I need match durations like the following:

- PT7S
- PT10M50S
- PT150S

Essentially I want the Regex to always check that:

- capitalised `PT` is at the beginning of the string
- M is preceded by a whole number
- S is preceded by a whole number
- M comes before S

My attempt so far:

- capitalised PT at the beginning = `^PT`
- M preceded by a whole number = `[0-9]+M` - except this allows something like `10.5M` because the `5M` counts
- S preceded by a whole number = same as above
- M comes before S. Again no idea!

I'm really stuck on trying to figure this out, I've been trying to get each part to match so I could try and combine them all later but I can't get over the first hurdle.

Comment: You need a dual regex expert with temporal dilation knowledge. Unfortunately, they don't exist. Not advisable to publish your results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't be much more complex than

```
const rxIso8601Duration = /^PT((([0-9]+M)?([0-9]+S))|([0-9]+M))$/ ;
```

Breaking it down:

```
^              // - anchor the match at start-of-text, followed by
PT             // - the literal PT, followed by
(              // - a group, consisting of either
  (            //   - a group, consisting of
    ([0-9]+M)? //     - an optional minutes designation, followed by
    ([0-9]+S)  //     - a required seconds designation
  )            //
  |            //   or
  ([0-9]+M)    //     - a required minutes designation
)              // the whole of which is followed by
$              // end-of-text
```

If you want to allow fractional minutes or seconds, Just change the appropriate sub-expression(s):

- `([0-9]+M)`
  recognizes patterns like `123M`, but not `123.456M`
- `([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?M)`
  will recognize not only `123M` but also matches `123.456M`

Comment: Amazing, thank you for laying it out so clearly. I was really struggling with how to string them together.